# Joining subquery using a column of outer query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-server-2017

This is my join query:

```
Select * 
    From MetricAlertMonitorings maa
        Left Join (
                    Select Top 1 *
                        From [dbo].MetricAlertMonitoringsDeliveredLog
                            Where maa.MetricAlertMonitoringID = [dbo].MetricAlertMonitoringsDeliveredLog.MetricAlertMonitoringID
                            Order By DeliveredDateTime asc
                ) mdl
                    ON maa.MetricAlertMonitoringID = mdl.MetricAlertMonitoringID
                Left Join (
                    Select Top 1 *
                        From [dbo].MetricAlertMonitoringsAcknowledgedLog
                            Where maa.MetricAlertMonitoringID = [dbo].MetricAlertMonitoringsAcknowledgedLog.MetricAlertMonitoringID
                            Order By MetricAlertMonitoringsStatusID asc, AcknowledgedDateTime asc
                ) mal
                    ON maa.MetricAlertMonitoringID = mal.MetricAlertMonitoringID
```

But somehow the query is not able to recognize column `maa.MetricAlertMonitoringID`. I get error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "maa.MetricAlertMonitoringID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
The multi-part identifier "maa.MetricAlertMonitoringID" could not be bound.
```

I need to join my query as a subquery. Any idea how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A joined subquery cannot reference a column from the outer query, hence the error that you are getting. I think that you ought to use `OUTER APPLY` instead:

```
Select * 
From MetricAlertMonitorings maa
outer apply (
    Select Top 1 *
    From [dbo].MetricAlertMonitoringsDeliveredLog
    Where maa.MetricAlertMonitoringID = [dbo].MetricAlertMonitoringsDeliveredLog.MetricAlertMonitoringID
    Order By DeliveredDateTime asc
) mdl
outer apply (
    Select Top 1 *
    From [dbo].MetricAlertMonitoringsAcknowledgedLog
    Where maa.MetricAlertMonitoringID = [dbo].MetricAlertMonitoringsAcknowledgedLog.MetricAlertMonitoringID
    Order By MetricAlertMonitoringsStatusID asc, AcknowledgedDateTime asc
) mal
```

Comment: amazing. So I just needed to use Outer Apply and remove the ON clause. Fantastic.. Thank you so much!!